# UnableToCompleteException with no log

Tags: java, exception, gwt

Trying to run my GWT app, I get

```
EntryPoint initialization exception

Exception while loading module ch.swisstph.mortqual.mqui.client.MqInput. See Development Mode for details.

com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:513)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:385)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

in the web browser, and just

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Xmx256m -Didea.launcher.port=7537 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/dhardy/code/download/idea-IU-129.239/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/install/gwt/gwt-dev.jar:/home/dhardy/p/mortqual/mqui/src:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/compilefontconfig.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rhino.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/javazic.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/java-atk-wrapper.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/pulse-java.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/home/dhardy/p/mortqual/mqui/out/test/mqui:/home/dhardy/p/mortqual/mqui/out/production/mqui:/home/install/appengine-java-sdk/lib/shared/jsp-api.jar:/home/install/appengine-java-sdk/lib/shared/appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar:/home/install/appengine-java-sdk/lib/shared/el-api.jar:/home/install/appengine-java-sdk/lib/shared/servlet-api.jar:/home/install/appengine-java-sdk/lib/user/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.5.jar:/home/install/gwt/gwt-user.jar:/home/dhardy/p/mortqual/anacod/target/test-classes:/home/dhardy/p/mortqual/anacod/target/classes:/home/dhardy/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.12/jxl-2.6.12.jar:/home/dhardy/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/home/dhardy/.m2/repository/com/beust/jcommander/1.30/jcommander-1.30.jar:/home/dhardy/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi/3.9-20130311/poi-3.9-20130311.jar:/home/dhardy/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.9/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar:/home/dhardy/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.9/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar:/home/dhardy/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.3.0/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:/home/dhardy/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/dhardy/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/dhardy/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:/home/install/gwt/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar:/home/install/gwt/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/home/dhardy/code/download/idea-IU-129.239/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode -war /home/dhardy/.IntelliJIdea12/system/gwt/mqui.5589a251/mqui.33ff3210/run/www -remoteUI 7901:IntelliJIdea -startupUrl mqInput.html ch.swisstph.mortqual.mqui.mqui
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Dev Mode initialized. Startup URL: 
http://127.0.0.1:8888/mqInput.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

on the command line. There are no logs I can find (I tried configuring log4j via a .properties file, which removed its warnings but still didn't give me any logs).

So how do I solve this?

The two most likely causes are renaming of my start-up page and pushing some code out to a library.

Comment: and in Console ?? any stackTrace ?

Comment: I've never launched a GWT DevMode session in IntelliJ IDEA but doesn't it open a new window? (the DevMode with, among other things, the logs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting -logLevel SPAM in your command line arguments, this will print detailed logs, also you can put explicit GWT.log("message") in your entry point code, that will tell your how far it is going (normal logging doesn't work directly with gwt).

This [page](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideDevMode) describes how to debug GWT in general, how ever my suggestion would be run debug this directly in eclipse with gwt plugin, GWT support in eclipse is amazing.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the GWT debug thing. (For anyone else, either look under IDEA's "modules" tab or copy the launch command onto a terminal and run outside the IDE.) Not following the Eclise suggestion, IDEA is more usable IMHO.